# How to change UINavigationItem font?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationitem

I am trying to change `font` property for `UINavigationItem`.

I've tried using `titleTextAttributes` but somehow I am only able to change title font.

How can I change the font or UINavigationItem ? For example, the "More" text for the Back `UIButton` shown below:

[image]

I've tried using:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(),
            NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Papyrus", size: 18)!
        ]
```

but it only changes what is shown on the picture, not the "More" Button's Font.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason your method wasn't working is because you were just using `titleTextAttributes = ...` when you have to use `setTitleTextAttributes:forState:` I use this function to customize the Nav Bar globally for my entire project:

```
func customizeNavBar(_ color: UIColor, titleFont: UIFont, buttonFont: UIFont) {

    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = color
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color, NSFontAttributeName: titleFont]
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color, NSFontAttributeName: buttonFont], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

For a single instance, call the same functions:

```
someBarButton.tintColor.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color, NSFontAttributeName: buttonFont], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: This changes font for all buttons, I need to change it for only one in specific class / Navigation Controller

Comment: Then instead of `UINavigationBar.appearance()` you call the same functions on an instance of UINavigationBar (Presumably `navigationController.navigationBar`) answer updated

Comment: I've tried that already, but I'm getting an error "UINavigationItem does not have a mamber named setTitleTextAttributes. Nor does navigationBar... I can only use the one I've presented in my initial post.. :< Edit: Check my initial post - I've added a code I'm using.

Comment: Nevermind, I was using NavigationItem instead of BarItem inside :) It's working now, thanks!

Comment: I need to just change the navigation title color and title font, i dont have any buttons on navigation item. Where to apply this function and how to use it '

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 15)!], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 13 and Swift 5.

For setting the bar button item text color & font:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.white, 
    .font: UIFont(name: GetFontNameBold(), size: 40)! ],
    for: UIControl.State.normal)
```

For setting the title color & font just add in *viewDidLoad()* the following line:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.white, 
    .font: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 24)! ]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have outlet do this:

```
titleItem.titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: NAME, size: SIZE)
```